# .htaccess give me trouble with some directory

Tags: php, redirect

I've this website: http://www.rolfgerard.com and this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^it/mostre.html exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/rolf_gerard.html rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/ausstellungen.html de/exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/rolf_gerard.html de/rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de de/index.php [L]
```

When I go in the "IT" part of the website all work good, when I go in the "DE" part my htaccess doesn't redirect me in the right file but it still remain the index.php file.

How do I fix this? :(

Full .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /

#RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+).html $2.php?lang=$1

# ITALIANO
RewriteRule ^it/thanks.html thanks.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/credits.html credits.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/privacy_policy.html privacy_policy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/link_media.html link_media.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/visitaci.html contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/contatto.html contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/chi_siamo.html about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/pubblicazioni.html books.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/opere.html works.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/mostre.html exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it/rolf_gerard.html rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it index.php [L]

# DEUTSCH
RewriteRule ^de/thanks.html de/thanks.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/credits.html de/credits.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/privacy_policy.html de/privacy_policy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/link_media.html de/link_media.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/besuchen.html de/contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/kontakt.html de/contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/uber_uns.html de/about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/publikationen.html de/books.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/works.html de/works.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/ausstellungen.html /de/exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/rolf_gerard.html de/rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de de/index.php [L]

# ENGLISH
RewriteRule ^en/thanks.html en/thanks.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/credits.html en/credits.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/privacy_policy.html en/privacy_policy.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/link_media.html en/link_media.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/visit_us.html en/contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/contact.html en/contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/about_us.html en/about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/books.html en/books.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/works.html en/works.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/exhibitions.html en/exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en/rolf_gerard.html en/rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^en en/index.php [L]

# ONLINE SHOP
RewriteRule ^online_shop/index_de.html online_shop/index_de.php [L]
RewriteRule ^online_shop/index_en.html online_shop/index_en.php [L]

# PRESS
RewriteRule ^press/index_de.html press/index_de.php [L]
RewriteRule ^press/index_en.html press/index_en.php [L]
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "/" at the beginning of the de rules

```
RewriteRule ^de/ausstellungen.html /de/exhibition.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de/rolf_gerard.html /de/rolf_gerard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^de$ /de/index.php [L]

...
RewriteRule ^en$ en/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^it$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Don't forget the 3rd rule, it needs a "/" too.

Comment: When I try one of these rules I receive a 500 Internal Server Error. If I don't write [R=301, L] but only [L] the error disapear but the rule still don't work.

Comment: where is files /de/rolf_gerard.ph on server? http://www.rolfgerard.com/de/rolf_gerard.php points to index.php i think the path is wrong.

Comment: I know, but physically the file is in the "/de/rolf_gerard.php" path. I don't know why it always points to the index.php file.

Comment: is this .htaccess file all? try with case insecitive,updated answer.